# in-app review is not opening when user click on button

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

in-app review is not opening when user click on button. I am using xamarin.forms android and using ref [link](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/StoreReviewPlugin/tree/master/src/StoreReviewTest/StoreReviewTest.Android)

i am using same code in github. I think i might be missing some thing

i downloaded nuget `StoreReviewPlugin` (version 2.0 latest)  to my shared & android project

```
  private async void OnRating_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              //i also tried true & false
                await CrossStoreReview.Current.RequestReview(false);
}
```

in my app, i dont have login page. could this be a issue?

Comment: is the method being executed?  Are you getting any sort of exception or log message?  Have you read the docs and followed all setup instructions?

Comment: yes i did. it just says to download nuget and put the following code

Comment: Check the setup of Android in the lin below. https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/StoreReviewPlugin/tree/master/src/StoreReviewTest/StoreReviewTest.Android Have you tried to download the source file from GitHub to test?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install PlayCore nuget package in your Android project to view the review dialog.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/PlayCore/?WT.mc_id=appreviews-blog-jamont

Also your app must be in the Testing phase and downloaded from the play store for it to work.

Here is a complete example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zE9J8Trwid4